# google-api-python-client best practice on creating service object

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

When using `google-api-python-client` When calling multiple methods like update, append etc. using `service` object created with

```
service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials`)
```

Is it a best practice to create the `service` object once and reuse it throughout the program or should I create new `service` objects each time with `discovery.build` when calling an API function like `service.spreadsheets().values().append`,`service.spreadsheets().values().get` etc.

Basically my question is can I use the same `service` service object multiple times in the application.

What is the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*As long as you are using the same API, you should use the same service object for each API method call.*

#### Further Information:

The only reason you would need to make multiple service objects is if your application was using different APIs (Drive, Gmail, Sheets, etc). The service object is a build of the API interaction which can be used as many times as you like within the same application to interact with the API to which it has been built.

Comment: When using flask, ist there a way to store the service object from one user request to the next? It seems like I would have to create a new one for every request.